# How to interchange primary and secondary axis in wxmaxima 2d plot

Tags: plot, 2d, maxima

Usually to make a graph in wxmaxima my code is

```
wxdraw2d(sin(x),[x,0,2*%pi]);
```

Is there a way to write the code as

```
wxdraw2d([x,0,2*%pi],sin(x));
```

in order to exchange the X and Y axes?

Answer (score 0):

One way to exchange the X and Y axes is to use `implicit`, like this:

```
draw2d (implicit (x=sin(y), x, -1, 1, y, -10, 10));
```

There may be another way, but I wasn't able to find anything else in a few minutes of searching.